# Converting SparkStreaming to Batch processing from real time In Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I have written the Kafka Producer and Consumer code for SparkStreaming, but it is working only for the real time updates in database.
Can you please let me know how to convert it into batch processing, so that it executes at-least-once.

**Producer Code:**

```
package com.test.anna.KafkaSpark;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

import scala.Array;
import scala.Product;
//import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import scala.collection.Iterator;

public class ProducerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "/Users/srikanth_kopparthy/Documents/keystore/client_jaas.conf");
//new
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

        properties.put("acks", "all");
        properties.put("retries", "0");
        properties.put("batch.size", "26384");
        properties.put("linger.ms", "1");
        properties.put("request.timeout.ms", "150000");
        properties.put("buffer.memory", "33554432");
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        //properties.put("partitioner.class", "SimplePartitioner");
       // properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", ProductsSerializer.class.getName());
        Producer producer = new KafkaProducer(properties);

        //JDBC Connection
     // JDBC driver name and database URL
         String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";  
         String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz:1976:cd";

        //  Database credentials
        String USER = "xyzzy";
         String PASS = "pwd";

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{
           //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
           Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

           //STEP 3: Open a connection
           System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

           //STEP 4: Execute a query
           System.out.println("Creating statement...");
           stmt = conn.createStatement();
           String sql;
           sql = "select * from test_mdm";
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
           System.out.println("RS-->"+rs.getRow()); 
           //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
           while(rs.next()){
              //Retrieve by column name
               System.out.println("inside whiel");
             String bo_id  = rs.getString("bo");
              String profile_cm_seq  = rs.getString("profile");
              String bo_cm_start_dt  = rs.getString("cm");
              Products product=new Products();
              product.setId(bo_id);
              product.setName(profile_cm_seq);
              product.setParents(bo_cm_start_dt);
              //Display values
              System.out.print("BO_ID: " + bo_id);
              Future response = producer.send(new ProducerRecord("test7", bo_id,product));
                  try {
                    response.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    while(response.isDone()) {
                        System.out.println(response.get().toString());
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Sent:" + bo_id);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    System.out.println("interrupted exception..");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                    System.out.println("execution exception..");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TimeoutException e1) {
                    System.out.println("TimeoutException..");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }



           }
           //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
           rs.close();
           stmt.close();
           conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
           //Handle errors for JDBC
           se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
           //Handle errors for Class.forName
           e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
           //finally block used to close resources
           try{
              if(stmt!=null)
                 stmt.close();
           }catch(SQLException se2){
           }// nothing we can do
           try{
              if(conn!=null)
                 conn.close();
           }catch(SQLException se){
              se.printStackTrace();
           }//end finally try
        }//end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");

        //JDBC Connection END






    }

}
```

**Consumer Code:**

```
package com.test.anna.KafkaSpark;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.HasOffsetRanges;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.OffsetRange;

import com.databricks.spark.avro.*;
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;  


public class SparkStreamingConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("kafka-sandbox")
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","localhost"); //for cassandra
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(30000));

        // TODO: processing pipeline
        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap();
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect","localhost:2181");
        Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("test7");
        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);

        directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            System.out.println("Message Received "+rdd.values().take(1));
            System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.partitions().size()
                + " partitions and " + rdd.count() + " records");
            rdd.foreach(record -> System.out.println(record));
           JavaRDD<String> rdd2=rdd.map(x ->(x._2));

           System.out.println("writing to cassandra");

           SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

           DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(rdd2);
           df.show();
           //producer-consumer-spark-streaming-dataframe-validation-transformation(avro)-kafka and cassandra    
           //Convert the dataframe to AVRO after validation

           if(df.count()>0)
           {
               //   df.write().mode("append").format("com.databricks.spark.avro").partitionby
               df.repartition(1).write().mode("append").format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("/Users/vipul.tripathi/AVRO Files/fifth");
               //DataFrame df5=sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/Users/xyz/AVRO Files/fifth/part-r-00000-d63f8878-20c3-4eea-9ee5-cdd62876c153.avro");
             // System.out.println("printing df5");
              //df5.show();
//          
//           df.select("bo_id").show();
//           df.registerTempTable("test");
//           DataFrame tempTest= sqlContext.sql("SELECT bo_id, profile_cm_seq,bo_cm_start_dt from test");
//           System.out.println("List temp table---->"+ tempTest);
//           tempTest.write().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").mode("append").options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
//               {
//                   put("keyspace", "java_api3");
//                   put("table", "prod");
//               }
//           }).save();
           }



        });

        directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
              OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
              rdd.foreachPartition(consumerRecords -> {
                OffsetRange o = offsetRanges[TaskContext.get().partitionId()];
                System.out.println(
                  o.topic() + " " + o.partition() + " " + o.fromOffset() + " " + o.untilOffset());
              });
            });

        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();  

    }       
}
```

Above is the Producer and consumer code. I want to run them and want to fetch the data that is already stored in the oracle database.

And how can I maintain the delta loading of records in this scenario??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to run a batch program to read all values from oracle and load in cassandra. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but using Kafka and Spark/DataSet only.

Comment: You can use Spark Sql and do it , why do you want to use kafka?. Spark streaming is made for near real time processing

Comment: its a project architecture that we are following. is it possible to convert the spark streaming code into batch one??

Comment: What do you mean by converting spark streaming to batch processing? Do you want it reads what is there on Kafka and then exit?

Comment: Yes, now if I update something in my database, then only consumer is running all the logics as I am using Future object.

I need something where it should the database first even though there is no changes done in DB.

Comment: In your case, producer is reading from oracle. So it you change producer to read delta records.it should be ok

Comment: okay.. so how to do that??? I am not getting any idea on this